# Unix /Linux - several applications using the same environment variables but different values?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am looking for some advice on the following below:

I have several applications and tools on a server that requires the environment to be set up with variables etc for them to run.

Many of these applications use  the same environment variables to run but with different values.

Some of these applications have multiple versions. e.g. `prog v1.1`, `prog v1.2`, `prog v1.3` etc..

> *Example:* `prog v1.1` uses environment variable `VAR1 = VAL1`, but `prog v1.2` needs `VAR1 = VAL2` in order to run. It is the same
>   variable, but different values required for each application.
>
> *Another example is:* `prog3` could require a number of environment variables set that `prog4` doesn't need.

There is also logic involved when setting up the environment for these applications, like `if file exists; do this; else do that`

I've created shell scripts *e.g. `prog1setup.sh`, `prog2setup.sh` etc* to setup the environment for each of these applications and then:

1. start a new shell for every application that needs to run,
2. run the shell script and then
3. run that application so it inherits the environment variables

---

What I'd like to know is, are there any open source tools available out there that can be used to better manage this as there could be lots of applications? I've been doing some research and came across tools such as **`launcherd`**, **`supervisor`** and **`Environment modules`** but I have not used any of these before.

If anyone has used any of those, please provide some insight on if it can apply here or is there something else that could be suggested?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned creating scripts, I would suggest creating `prog1.sh` with

```
#!/bin/bash
export VAR1=VAL1
prog1 "$@"
```

and creating `prog2.sh` with

```
#!/bin/bash
export VAR1=VAL2
prog2 "$@"
```

Then, never run `prog1` or `prog2` directly.  Instead, run `prog1.sh` or `prog2.sh`.  Since a shell scripts environment never affects the calling shell, the variable `VAR1` will only exist when needed and will disappear once the script finishes executing.

#### Alternative

Some people prefer functions to scripts because function definitions can be conveniently stored in `~/.bashrc`.  As examples of functions that set needed environment variables:

```
date2() ( export TZ=Asia/Tokyo; date "$@" )
date3() ( export TZ=Europe/Paris; date "$@" )
```

These can be used as follows:

```
$ date2
Wed Jul  8 14:49:30 JST 2015
$ date3
Wed Jul  8 07:49:31 CEST 2015
```

Comment: You can write those functions like `date2() (export TZ=...; date "$@")` -- without the braces.

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, thanks:  all that is needed is a compound command.